# Ignition coil connector on my 1978 jeep wagoner

Tags: jeep, ignition-coil, connector

I am looking to replace my Ignition coil connector on my 1978 jeep wagoner.  As one of the wires is not attached. The one I am seeing online do not look like original. The original has three wires coming out of it. One positive, one ground,and one the go to what I think  is the jump connector. The only ones online I see over two wires. The ground and the positive.

Does any one know if it is not needed or a place that I can find one.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

It should only take two wires, which are actually the positive from the battery (or if equipped, the ballast resistor) and one to the distributor which is the trigger for firing. If there is a ballast resistor, there could be a third wire which would provide full voltage to the coil during startup. IIRC, this would also go to the positive post on the coil.

Realistically, you really don't even need the connector if there are threaded posts on the coil. You could just terminate the wires which are there with eye connectors and screw them into the correct posts on the coil. It would work just fine. Just a thought.